# Typescript not inferring type with conditional statements

Tags: typescript

```
declare const lucky: boolean;
declare const str: string;
declare const nil: null;

const random = lucky ? str : nil;
// random: string | null

if (lucky) {
  // random: string | null
  // should be string
}
```

Are there any workarounds to achieve similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how type inferance in TS works.

Type checks apply to the checked variable and not other variables which values may be related to the checked variable.

Type inferance doesn't event work for variable aliases, which is a much more simple case.

```
const lucky: boolean | null =  Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : true;

const random = lucky;

if (lucky) {
  lucky //this is true
  random // this is true | null
}
```

You can see this in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgV2AawJ4C4YCMQjgUwEMwYAfGMBOOGAXhhgFlCoALAOgCdiATEAWwAUAShgAeGAAZ2AVhgB+ClRqYonBPgDcAKG2hIsbmD7868JGh3aAlgDMYgxClSiA3toZO0MAPQ+21hAwgTBqGh4wRia+PqGsISFh+GRK1NoAvkA)